# XML handle response error with external access

Tags: javascript, php, xml, ajax

I have an JavaScript(AJAX) code which takes data from an php file (Pagerank Script which returns an variable $prr=6 where 6 is pagerank of the verified link) using GET and transform it in xml file to become handable for java.

This is the function wich creates Xml Http Request:

```
 var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
var xmlHttp;

if(window.ActiveXObject){
    try{
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}else{
    try{
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e){
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}
if(!xmlHttp)
    alert("Nu pot crea XML!");
else
    return xmlHttp;
```

}

This is the process function:

```
 window.onload = function process(){
 if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    link = encodeURIComponent(value = 'google.ro');
    local = '/v1.php?verifica=';
    xmlHttp.open("GET", local+link,true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}else{

}

}
```

And this is Handle the response of the server:

```
 function handleServerResponse(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    if(xmlHttp.status==200){
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
        message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
        document.getElementById("Raspuns").innerHTML = message;

    }else{
        alert("Probleme cu datele returnate de server!");
    }
}
}
```

I have an document writer for generating id tag for getElementById()

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://verificapagerank.32biti.com/java/verifica.js"></script> <div id="Raspuns"></div>');
```

This is the code for including javascript file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://verificapagerank.32biti.com/java/calculator.js"></script>
```

All is fine until i put the code on external site!
On external files I get alert error from `handleServerResponse()`

```
`Probleme cu datele returnate de server!`
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is because the "Same Origin Policy". Not big into JS and don't know Jquery enough to give a solid answer, but I believe this would be a good place to start. Do a google search for "AJAX Same Origin Policy" and you should get all the info you need ;)

Comment: I will try to inform me from there, thank's